# How can I mask an object to allow another object to show through?

Tags: node-editor, masking

I have an outer eye and an inner eye.  I'd like the blue iris to show through the outer eye.  In my source files shown below, I've got a couple masks.

I suspect the answer is an image texture node with the mask file, but I'm not sure how to set that up.

If another solution seems better, I'm open to suggestions.

For reference, the .blend is [here](http://[%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=a6jxlEkp%22%20/%3E](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/a6jxlEkp/)).
Thanks!

[image: eye]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you would combine the 2 images using a mix shader, and use the mask image as the mix factor. See Below:

[image: ImageMask]

Comment: This works if I want to use two images on ONE object, but I'm looking to have the iris be a separate object.  Is there a way to mask the eye and have the iris show through?

Comment: Oh, 2 objects you say? That's interesting... I'm not sure I've ever done anything like that. Hang on, let me try some things..

Comment: Ok, In case I don't manage to replicate your issue tonight, here's my thinking - For the outer eye (the one you want to have a see through portion), use the mask as the alpha for that material (remember to set the blend mode to anything but opaque in the material properties tab). This should make a "hole" that can be seen through. For the other material (iris), use the mask (again as alpha) to "cut away" the black from around the circle (if necessary). Once you place the objects together, you SHOULD be able to see one through the other. I will have a better description once I can test it.

Comment: Upon further inspection, you can probably omit the second part of my suggestion regarding the iris, as it seems you already have that set up just fine.

Comment: Its entirely possible I'm making it more difficult than it needs to be.  I got a great result with your original suggestion.  The tutorial that suggested a two object eye is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0r0UnaIK_Y

Comment: Yeah, I see. I just watched the video..... oh the good 'ol days of blender before the Principled BSDF - endless node webs that go on to eternity.... But I see, the person in the video uses the mask as a mix factor between the shiny/translucent center of the eye and the (mainly) diffuse texture of the outer eye, which is quite similar to what i'm suggesting. I think in the end, if the number of objects doesn't matter, go with whatever approach works/looks best.